# ASP.Net Core 2.1 ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT value not reflecting

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, environment-variables, asp.net-core-2.1, windows-server-2012

I have `ASP.Net Core 2.1` API app. It is supposed to host in 4 environments.

1. Development
2. Testing
3. Staging
4. Production

When running the app in local from Visual Studio, the app is rightly fetching the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable & accordingly fetching the values from appsettings.Development.json

[image: Local Dev Machine]

But when the same deployed in a VM, it's not fetching the environment & looking for settings (like Connection string etc.) from appsettings.json.

[image: Test Environment]

**What else settings I need to do so?**

Thanks!

Comment: Check this out. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: @cleftheris Thanks! as per the above link I added the below settings in launchsettings.json 
https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=da032fc0d3ef4fc9a1d75bc88b1f7c18

Comment: @cleftheris but when added, its throwing runtime error 500 - The requested address is not valid in its context

Comment: launchSettings.json is only used by `dotnet run` ( i.e. inside Visual Studio), it's more than useless for deployment to IIS.

Comment: @Kgn-web You should check the section called "set-the-environment" in the documentation above. Assuming you are running on windows according to the docs you can either. A. Set a windows global environment variable through the system settings. B. Set the environment variable through web.config. The `B` option is easier.

Comment: @Kgn-web One more thing. If your environment is set correctly inside the VM  (lets say to "Testing") and your issue is your settings are not loaded from the expected `appSettings.Testing.json` then please update your question to reflect that. For example you may need to change your Program.cs to use the `CreateDefaultBuilder`.

Comment: @cleftheris, actually as you mentioned in your comments that I was setting the user variable rather than environment variables. Doing so , desired appsettings is reflecting.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be setting **System** Environment Variable rather than **User** Variable.

Comment: As more context, you're adding the environment variable for *your* user profile, i.e. the one you're logged into the machine as. That is almost certainly not the same user that the App Pool in IIS is running as. As such, it has no access to any environment variables set on your user profile. You can add a user variable, but it has to be done on the user that the App Pool is running as. Otherwise, a system variable will be accessible to all users.

Comment: @ChrisPratt, can you please check the error mentioned in the comments? Thanks!